# Completely format and remove a hardrive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, filesystems, formatting

[image: http://i.imgur.com/99uMOrG.jpg.]
As seen in image disk1 is paritioned in 3 parts (C,E&F) I have nothing to do with it.
All I need to do is format and remove all partitions from disk2 that is partitioned as D and other two unecessary partitions. Naturally i have to change the system folder to some other drive so explain me how.

Comment: your OS is Windows 7?

Comment: So, basically you’re saying Windows is installed on `D:`, right? Is it an option to reinstall the system? Moving Windows isn’t that simple.

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on *Computer* in the start menu and select **Manage**
- In the left list select **Disk Management**

[image]

You can delete each partition , just right click on it and select delete!!